# Table name as variable in sql string

Tags: python, sql

can someone tell me how to make the table a variable?

```
tableX = "test"

sql = "SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE datum = %s and name = %s"  
val = (datumX, nameX,)
```

I just can't get it right. I've tried {}and also s%.

Thanks

Comment: try this: sql = f"SELECT * FROM {tableX} WHERE datum = %s and name = %s"

Comment: Could you elaborate on what database you intend to connect and what connector you will use for that.

Comment: How would you put a variable in any other string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use format function or f-string(if python 3.6=<)

```
tableX = "test"
sql = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE datum = %s and name = %s".format(tableX)
```

Comment: Great with that, why is everything so complicated in Python :)

Answer (score 1):

In Python2.x works first answer:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE datum = %s and name = %s" .format(tableX)
```

In Python3 you can use second one with f-string:

`sql = f"SELECT * FROM {tableX} WHERE datum = %s and name = %s"`

But, beware of SQL injection. You must be absolutely sure about source of that tableX variable (no user input). By direct format of the string you by-pass all escaping of input.